# Selecting top row in a many to many relationship with custom join table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have three tables in a M-M relationship:

[image]

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how I can retrieve all Bundles with only the first related inventory item ordered by `Inventory.Stock ASC` but also return the `Bundles_Inventory.InventoryRequired` field.

I've seen other responses to similar questions but none of them take into account a custom join table.

**How can I select all Bundles ordered by Inventory.Stock ASC and also include Bundles_Inventory.InventoryRequired for that record?**

In regards to @imran
Originally I had:

```
SELECT b.Id, b.Name, i.Id, i.Name, i.Stock, bi.InventoryRequired from         Bundles b
INNER JOIN Bundles_Inventory bi ON b.Id = bi.BundleId
INNER JOIN Inventory i ON bi.InventoryId = i.Id
WHERE b.ClientId = @clientId
ORDER BY i.Stock ASC
```

But obviously this gets me duplicate data in regards to the `Bundles` table..

I then tried

```
SELECT TOP 1 b.Id, b.Name, i.Id, i.Name, i.Stock, bi.InventoryRequired from Bundles b
INNER JOIN Bundles_Inventory bi ON b.Id = bi.BundleId
INNER JOIN Inventory i ON bi.InventoryId = i.Id
WHERE b.ClientId = @clientId
ORDER BY i.Stock ASC
```

And right now I'm trying to figure out how I can apply a `Group By` to figure this out.

Comment: what you have tried before ?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MS Sql Server..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `row_number()` in most databases:

```
select b.*, i.*
from bundles b join
     (select i.*,
             row_number() over (partition by bi.bundleid order by i.stock desc) as seqnum
      from bundles_inventory bi join
           Inventory i 
           on bi.InventoryId = i.Id
     ) i
     on b.id = bi.bundleid 
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can add the `where` clause in the outer query.